# Option 81 in DHCP

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, dhcpd, dhcp-option

Just curious about this.

When we enable option 81 on a DHCP network, the DHCP server will start updating the zone that comes along with the client's FQDN.

Now, how would client will ever know its domain even before getting an IP address?

My apologies if the question sounds dumb.

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Two locations:

1. [Configure the Primary DNS Suffix for a Client Computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794784(v=ws.10).aspx).
2. [Configure a Connection-Specific DNS Name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816716(v=ws.10).aspx)